# Android SwitchCompat onCheckedChangeListener doesn't work

Tags: android, switchcompat

This is my code and it doesn't work for me.
I use code from [this](http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/android-switch-button-example/) example.

Xml -

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:id="@+id/visibility_switch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/mat_card_padding"
            app:showText="false" />
```

And code:

```
mVisibilitySwitchCompat = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.visibility_switch);
mVisibilitySwitchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {             

                    // this method doesn't work!

                    if (isChecked) {
                        mVisibilityTextView.setText(getString(R.string.visibility_on));
                    } else {
                        mVisibilityTextView.setText(getString(R.string.visibility_off));
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: this should be  `mVisibilityTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.visibility_on));`

Comment: @MD no need of getResources() now

Comment: @KrupalShah why not?

Comment: @MD http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int) has been added. you can try it.

Comment: @OP can you post your whole layout xml?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a listener, try the [`setTextOff()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html#setTextOff%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) and [`setTextOn()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html#setTextOn%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) methods. The Switch will automatically handle setting the correct one when the checked state changes.

Comment: Can I catch switch events or click on the SwitchCompat?

Comment: @Artem Yes you should be able to do most things you can do with any other View. It's just that it's automatically handling the text it displays so your `setText()` calls get ignored or overridden.